# TeamCity Build Fails Because NUnit is Locking Files?

Tags: .net, nunit, teamcity, nunit-console, teamcity-5.1

We have been having an issue with our project's Continuous Integration. Occasionally, we want to try to clean all of the files on build within TeamCity in its checkout directory. Whenever we try to do this, `nunit-agent.exe` ends up remaining open from the previous build, yielding the following errors:

```
[05:35:40]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] Failed to delete file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\path\to\UnitTestResults.xml
[05:35:40]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] Failed to delete file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\path\to\src\packages\NUnit.2.5.7.10213\Tools\lib\nunit-console-runner.dll
[05:35:40]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] Failed to delete file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\path\to\src\packages\NUnit.2.5.7.10213\Tools\lib\nunit.core.dll
[05:35:40]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] Failed to delete file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\path\to\src\packages\NUnit.2.5.7.10213\Tools\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll
[05:35:40]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] Failed to delete file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\path\to\src\packages\NUnit.2.5.7.10213\Tools\lib\nunit.util.dll
[05:35:40]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] Failed to delete file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\path\to\src\packages\NUnit.2.5.7.10213\Tools\nunit-agent.exe
```

We always have to ask someone who has access to the box to manually kill the process before the build starts working again. What reasons would NUnit have to remain open indefinitely (we can wait 24 hours and it'll still be hanging)? Is there some command we need to use in our build script to force it to terminate, or to tell TeamCity that if a program hangs to force close it?

Comment: How are you running NUnit - are you running it yourself from a script, or using using the TeamCity NUnit runner in a build step?

Comment: Running it myself from an exe included in the repository itself (nunit-console.exe).

Comment: monitor the processes that are running on the build agent when your build executes. You are probably not terminating nunit-console.exe when it has finished running the tests, leaving a lingering process after the build completes.

Comment: Having this issue too.  Running Nunit via psake.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Running NUnit from my script, I see that the nunit-agent-x86.exe process isn't disposing properly.  Looking into how to ensure they close since it'll probably be the same issue as you are having.

Comment: Have you specified `/m` switch to run tests in parallel? If so use (can't recall exctly) `/vr:f` switch as well.

Comment: @sil nunit-console.exe doesn't have a `/m` nor a `/vf:f` switch.

Comment: Did you get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired setting the 'fail build if it runs lonnger than x' setting?

See http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/1.General+Settings

> Check this option and enter a value in
>   minutes to enable time control on the
>   build. If the specified amount of time
>   is exceeded, the build is
>   automatically canceled. This option
>   helps to deal with builds that hang
>   and maintains agent efficiency.

Comment: Yep, that's set to 10 minutes. This occurs immediately after the build begins (since the NUnit process never quits even if the build fails).

Answer (score 0):

No stunning insights on my part, only the obvious:

1. Updating to the latest version usually helps.
2. Is the failing "Full Build (dev branch)" the only configuration using "agent side checkout"? The others I looked at all use "server side checkout". I'm no expert on the difference, but are you sure you need it?

Comment: This type of failure has also occurred on the Default branch build. It basically happens whenever "Clean all files before build" is checked within TeamCity settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.  I upgraded to 2.6.012035 and it is now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Swabra plugin, Luke
It is included by default